# How To Create R Data Frame From List In Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm having trouble returning data frames from a loop in R. I have a set of functions that reads in files and turns them into data frames for the larger project to use/visualize.

I have a list of file names to pass:

```
# list of files to read
frameList <-c("apples", "bananas", "pears")
```

This function iterates over the list and runs the functions to create the data frames if they are not already present.

```
populateFrames <- function(){
    for (frame in frameList){
        if (exists(frame) && is.data.frame(get(frame))){
            # do nothing
        }
        else {
            frame <- clean_data(gather_data(frame))
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, the function runs with no errors, but does not save any data frame to the environment.

I can manually run the same thing and that saves a data frame:

```
# manually create "apples" data frame
apples <- clean_data(gather_data(frameList[1]))
```

From my reading through similar questions here, I see that assign() is used for similar things. But in the same way as before, I can run the code manually fine; but when put inside the loop no data frame is saved to the environment.

```
# returns a data frame, "apples" to the environment 
assign(x = frame[1], value = clean_data(gather_data(frame[1])))
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are creating a data frame in the local scope of your function, and when your program leaves that scope, your data is not saved. Try running the for loop outside of the function.

Comment: In R terminology, `c("apples", "bananas", "pears")` is a character vector, not a list. This is an important distinction as solutions may differ depending on the type of object involved.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions, following the principle of "change as little about the OPs implementation as possible".

You have two problems here.

1. Your function is not returning anything, so any changes that happen are stuck in the environment of the function
2. I think you're expecting the re-assignment of `frame`in the `else`statement to re-assign it to that element in frameList. It's not.

This is the NOT RECOMMENDED* way of doing this where you assign a variable in the function's parent environment. In this case you are *populatingFrames* as a side effect, mutating the `frameList` in the parent environment. Mutating the input is generally something you want to avoid if you want to practice defensive programming.

```
populateFrames <- function(){
    for (i in seq_along(frameList)){
        if (exists(frameList[[i]]) && is.data.frame(get(frameList[[i]]))){
            # do nothing
        }
        else {
            frameList[[i]] <<- clean_data(gather_data(frameList[[i]]))
        }
    }
}
```

This is the RECOMMENDED version where you return the new frameList (which means you have to assign it to a value).

```
populateFrames <- function(){
    for (i in seq_along(frameList)){
        if (exists(frameList[[i]]) && is.data.frame(get(frameList[[i]]))){
            # do nothing
        }
        else {
            frameList[[i]] <- clean_data(gather_data(frameList[[i]]))
        }
    }
    frameList
}
```

Comment: `frame <<-` will assign to an object named "frame", right?

Comment: OP might want to use assign with `envir = .GlobalEnv`

Comment: `frame <<- ` will look for `frame` in the parent environment, and update it with the right operand (here `clean_data(gather_data(frame))`).  If it doesn't exist in the parent environment, it keeps moving up the search tree until it either finds `frame`,  or gets to `.GlobalEnv`, at which poitn it sets it there

Comment: If this function isn't intended to be used as part of a package, or in some other environment structure, this will work as intended. Otherwise, @WalkerintheCity's suggestion would be preferred.

Comment: Yes, the use case here is outside of a package. Just a simple shiny app that loads data from files users save. @WalkerintheCity's suggestion seems to be what I need here.

Comment: @sastrup check the edits. Another look at your code made me realize what I think you intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding global variable assignments, which are typically a no-no, try lapply:

```
lapply(
  frameList,
  function(frame){
    if(exists(frame) && is.data.frame(get(frame))){
      frame
    }else{
      clean_data(gather_data(frame))
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This will produce a list of tables, which you can put together with a rbindlist, or what have you.